# Radio button page in inno setup uninstaller

Tags: radio-button, inno-setup, uninstallation

I've seen a lot of questions like this, but never this exactly, so I was wondering if this is even possible, and if not what is an alternative?

I want to have a page with three options:

1. Delete game, savegames, missions, players, etc. (basically everything)
2. Delete the game and savegames and such, but leave certain files.
3. Delete just the game, and leave everything else.

Then I'd have to make it delete certain files, and SAVE certain files depending on what they selected.

Is that possible?

Comment: What's your question - how to create page with these three radiobuttons or how to delete/save certain files depending on what's selected?

Comment: Well, have you read the help file, topic "Pascal Scripting: Using Custom Wizard Pages"? Should get you started, there is also examples which come with Inno.

Comment: Well I've read all that...but the examples only show message boxes in the uninstaller...and I haven't seen how to make an actual page. I've made custom pages in the install...but I can't figure out how in the UNinstaller :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create wizard pages during uninstall (The exception being the progress page) as it doesn't have the same wizard.

You can however show custom forms (See `CreateCustomForm()` and its `ShowModal()` method) and message boxes.

Once the form has been closed, you can get the values from the controls and delete whatever is required.